# Missing initialization step with C++ hotloader/run time linker

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

To facilitate run-time C++ programming I've made a small run=time C++ hotloader which loads and links object files while a program is running. It works by copying the sections from the clang-compiled object file into memory, handling the adjusted relocations and calling the global initializers in the .CRT$XCU sections as needed. All this worked without a hitch with clang in visual studio 2013 compatibility mode but since upgrading my compiler to Visual studio 2015 and setting the compatibility mode for VS2015 appropriately it appears there may be some new initialization mechanism which has been introduced which I haven't yet accounted for. I noticed this affecting calls to printf, eg. given:

```
printf("This is the number 5: %d %d %d\n", 5, 5, 5);
printf("This is the number 15: %d\n", 15);
printf("This is the number 30: %d\n", 30);
```

During execution it appears that printf isn't getting the right address, it seems to get called with uninitialized memory for some reason:

This is the number 5: -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
This is the number 15: -858993460
This is the number 30: -858993460

The same thing with a string instead:

```
printf("str: %s\n", "hello");
```

Exception thrown at 0x0F6B3F7D (ucrtbased.dll) in script-example.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

I'm hoping someone with knowledge of the MSVC internals knows what I'm missing here. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: *Why* are you doing all this yourself instead of using the existing Windows API functions to load dynamically? Also, are you really loading *object files* and not finished and linked executables or DLLs?

Comment: I wanted to create a completely self contained run time C++ programming/scripting system for people to use. As I mentioned the object code is dynamically linked at run time. Unfortunately there are some minor hiccups that I lack the expertise to fix which may mean I need to fall back on using modules after all.